# Memory leakage in mysql DB server

Tags: mysql, innodb

Environment :  Azure Instance 32GB RAB 8 Core CPU . Data is 10GB
After weekly restart I observed it memory get increase by 5% everyday , like initial restartd it will 12% then when I monitor every morning it always show 5% more
like end of week it reach 40% , regardless any actives . while CPU is very normal , it alway below 5% . Here is my mysql configure file

```
[mysqld]
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
log-error       = /var/log/mysql/error.log
bind-address    = 0.0.0.0
default_authentication_plugin= mysql_native_password
sql-mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
#max_connections = 5000
max_connections=5000     # change on 03/10/20202 by Debashis
innodb_buffer_pool_size=18G # change on 03/10/20202 by Debashis
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=28
sort_buffer_size=100M
join_buffer_size=100M
tmp_table_size=1G
max_heap_table_size=1G  # added on 03/10/20202 by Debashis
innodb_log_file_size = 1G

# Below  added on 03/10/20202 by Debashis
innodb_log_buffer_size = 67108864

innodb_io_capacity_max = 6000
innodb_io_capacity = 4000
innodb_read_io_threads = 16
innodb_thread_concurrency = 0
innodb_write_io_threads = 16

table_open_cache=13806
open_files_limit= 27612
table_definition_cache=7303
```

Heres is the  performence Tuner report .. I did not see much issue on the report ..

```
 -- MYSQL PERFORMANCE TUNING PRIMER --
      - By: Matthew Montgomery -

MySQL Version 8.0.20 x86_64

Uptime = 2 days 0 hrs 11 min 20 sec
Avg. qps = 15
Total Questions = 2651288
Threads Connected = 22

Server has been running for over 48hrs.
It should be safe to follow these recommendations

To find out more information on how each of these
runtime variables effects performance visit:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html
Visit http://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/advisors.html
for info about MySQL's Enterprise Monitoring and Advisory Service

SLOW QUERIES
The slow query log is NOT enabled.

BINARY UPDATE LOG
The binary update log is enabled
The expire_logs_days is not set.
The mysqld will retain the entire binary log until RESET MASTER or PURGE MASTER LOGS commands are run manually
Setting expire_logs_days will allow you to remove old binary logs automatically
See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/purge-master-logs.html

WORKER THREADS
Current thread_cache_size = 68
Current threads_cached = 48
Current threads_per_sec = 0
Historic threads_per_sec = 0
Your thread_cache_size is fine

MAX CONNECTIONS
Current max_connections = 6000
Current threads_connected = 20
Historic max_used_connections = 80
The number of used connections is 1% of the configured maximum.
You are using less than 10% of your configured max_connections.
Lowering max_connections could help to avoid an over-allocation of memory
See "MEMORY USAGE" section to make sure you are not over-allocating

INNODB STATUS
Current InnoDB index space = 10.38 G
Current InnoDB data space = 10.12 G
Current InnoDB buffer pool free = 73 %
Current innodb_buffer_pool_size = 18.00 G
Depending on how much space your innodb indexes take up it may be safe
to increase this value to up to 2 / 3 of total system memory

MEMORY USAGE
Max Memory Ever Allocated : 33.74 G
Configured Max Per-thread Buffers : 1175.85 G
Configured Max Global Buffers : 18.07 G
Configured Max Memory Limit : 1193.92 G
Physical Memory : 31.36 G

Max memory limit exceeds 90% of physical memory

KEY BUFFER
No key reads?!
Seriously look into using some indexes
Current MyISAM index space = 0 bytes
Current key_buffer_size = 8 M
Key cache miss rate is 1 : 0
Key buffer free ratio = 81 %
Your key_buffer_size seems to be fine

QUERY CACHE
You are using MySQL 8.0.20, no query cache is supported.
I recommend an upgrade to MySQL 4.1 or better

SORT OPERATIONS
Current sort_buffer_size = 100 M
Current read_rnd_buffer_size = 256 K
Sort buffer seems to be fine

JOINS
Current join_buffer_size = 100.00 M
You have had 13855 queries where a join could not use an index properly
join_buffer_size >= 4 M
This is not advised
You should enable "log-queries-not-using-indexes"
Then look for non indexed joins in the slow query log.

OPEN FILES LIMIT
Current open_files_limit = 10000 files
The open_files_limit should typically be set to at least 2x-3x
that of table_cache if you have heavy MyISAM usage.
Your open_files_limit value seems to be fine

TABLE CACHE
Current table_open_cache = 13806 tables
Current table_definition_cache = 7303 tables
You have a total of 4602 tables
You have 6755 open tables.
The table_cache value seems to be fine

TEMP TABLES
Current max_heap_table_size = 1.00 G
Current tmp_table_size = 1.00 G
Of 114648 temp tables, 0% were created on disk
Created disk tmp tables ratio seems fine

TABLE SCANS
Current read_buffer_size = 128 K
Current table scan ratio = 181 : 1
read_buffer_size seems to be fine

TABLE LOCKING
Current Lock Wait ratio = 0 : 2651593
Your table locking seems to be fine
```

Comment: As data is 10 GB so no point to keep buffer pool more than 10 GB and Memory will utilize as per configuration which included cache warmup or in memory.

Comment: Debashis, You have 10GB Innodb index space used and 10GB Innodb data space used.
To improve RAM data and index residency, (for higher performance) 20G X 1.4 = 28G would be reasonable.  But then you only have 32GB RAM total. Until you have more RAM available, 32G * .6 = 19G for Innodb_buffer_pool_size AND 16 for Innodb_buffer_pool_instances should cover your instance count up to 128GB total RAM.  To conserve 90% of CPU cycles used for the function of innodb_lru_scan_depth=100 will improve performance rather than the default value of 1024.

Comment: Additional information request. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Your InnoDB buffer pool size is huge.

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=18G # change on 03/10/20202 by Debashis
```

This means that the buffer can consume up to 18 GB RAM, which would explain the big memory usage in your server.

The memory consumption shouldn't grow too far beyond those 18 GB. If that is a concern to you, read [Configuring InnoDB Pool Size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-buffer-pool-resize.html) and set it to a smaller value.

Answer (score -1):

That's not a memory leak, that's caches warming up. Also, as Marc pointed out above, there is no benefit to having the buffer pool bigger than your data size.

Your sort and join buffer sizes are absurdly large. Default is 256KB which is sensible for most uses. Note that this is the minimum amount that will get allocated per connection.

And if you don't know exactly what you are doing already, don't use mysql tuner - in the vast majority of cases blindly following its advice will do more harm than good.

Comment: @debashis-mallick Remember, innodb_buffer_pool_size supports table data and table index data - in your case ~ 20G  and MySQL sets aside for change management - innodb_change_buffer_max_size to improve processing speed.  In your case, you likely are setting aside 25% of the buffer_pool_size. Tuning is an ongoing process for busy systems and requires observations and consideration from time to time.